# SSRS error Index was outside the bounds of the array. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a report in SSRS and i am getting an the error: `Index was outside the bounds of the array (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)`.

I have tried different expressions to fix this but I can't make it work. I currently have:

```
=iif(LEN(Fields!Comment.Value) - LEN(REPLACE(Fields!Comment.Value, ",","")) > 3, Split(Fields!Comment.Value, ",")(3), Nothing)
```

Could anyone advice me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error has to do with SSRS trying to evaluate the split expression even if the Iif condition is false.

Instead of the static value of 3 as the array index you can use a nested Iif to return a valid index value like 0, to make split always work.

```
=iif(
    LEN(Fields!Comment.Value) - LEN(REPLACE(Fields!Comment.Value, ",","")) >3
    , Split(Fields!Comment.Value, ",")(
        iif(
            LEN(Fields!Comment.Value) - LEN(REPLACE(Fields!Comment.Value, ",","")) >3
            ,3
            ,0
            )
    ) 
, Nothing
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much i tried this and it worked perfectly!